# create a new installable zip from a ( already installed ) Joomla 1.7 component

Tags: installation, reverse-engineering, joomla1.7, jcomponent

I've Joomla 1.7 and lots of component in it.

I'd like to make a "reverse-engineering" of the install of a component.

I've edited most part of it and i'd like to repack this to install in a new fresh Joomla installation.

Any idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly straight forward - you download all the related files then zip them up with a new XML manifest. Of course you have to make sure that you get all of the files because they can be located in a couple different places. Luckily, the Joomla documentation has a basic list of all the files you would find in a component.

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!1.7_-_Part_14#Packaging_the_component

Comment: Thanks Brent, what about mysql? it's not mentioned in your answer

Comment: You will have to open up the original package to see if it makes any changes to the DB. You'd then need to combine those with any changes you made during modification. The tutorial covers where and how to execute any SQL in the install process.