# How to package a Joomla module?

Tags: joomla

I have a Joomla module extension deployed on several sites. Sadly, the developer went out of business. I haven't got the zip any more, but I do need that extension deployed on another site.

Is it possible to take the deployed module, and package it again? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Which version of Joomla ?

Comment: ...this page seems appropriately migrated to the Joomla StackExchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to extract module's files (/modules/mod_...) and adapt them to render the module installable. You should follow these [rules](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module/fr).
Look also at this similare answer (for Joomla 1.7) [create a new installable zip from a ( already installed ) Joomla 1.7 component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281302/create-a-new-installable-zip-from-a-already-installed-joomla-1-7-component)